# Using DocuSign SOAP API to send to a signing group removes all tags

Tags: docusignapi

We're using Salesforce and the DocuSign SOAP API to send documents for signature. For a specific case we have created a template in DocuSign and are using the SOAPs CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates method to create the envelope for this template.

In this particular case, the template has two roles. The first role is always an individual signer but the second role is to be a signing group. Each role has tags on the envelope to fill out.

I set up the recipients in the API, using the signingGroupId for the signing group and send away. The first recipient is able to interact with the document without issues, but the second recipient - the signing group - opens the document to find the tags they should be able to interact with gone.

If I explicitly set the second recipient to be an individual and not a signing group, the tags for the second recipient persist. But they get blown away when the recipient is set as a signing group. Is there any way to use the DocuSign SOAP API to set a recipient as a signing group and *not* have the tags for the recipient be removed from the template?

Answer (score 2):

You are using an older not quite deprecated method. Try using CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms as this link suggests. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/reference/sending-group/createenvelopefromtemplates/